# Inconsistent behaviour when invoking same function from different places

Tags: c, function, pointers, printf

As part of a team assignment I have to create a program that reads an assembly source file and produces binary code for a specific architecture.

I created the function **tokenize** to split a string into tokens based on a pattern provided.

The problem I encountered is that when invoking **toks_print()** from **main()** the last two lines (tokens) are illegible whereas when **toks_print()** is called from **read_assembly_file()** the result is consistent.

This is the output as printed onto stdout:

This is the file read:
ldr r0,=0x20200004
ldr r2,[r0]
cmp r2,r0
andeq r0,r0,r0

Printing 4 tokens:
ldr r0,=0x20200004
ldr r2,[r0]
cmp r2,r0
andeq r0,r0,r0

Printing 4 tokens:
ldr r0,=0x20200004
ldr r2,[r0]
c¿
\370\277_\377¿

My question is: why is this happening? 
I'm sure it has something to do with pointers 
but for the life of me I can't figure it out.
This also happens with any other file I tried: the last lines are missing or 
indecipherable.

For completeness this is the content of gpio_0.s:
ldr r0,=0x20200004
ldr r2,[r0]
cmp r2,r0
andeq r0,r0,r0

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef struct Tokens
{
    char **toks;
    unsigned int tokno;
} Tokens;


Tokens *toks_new() 
{   
    Tokens *tokens = malloc(sizeof(Tokens));
    tokens->toks   = malloc(sizeof(char **));
    return tokens;
}


void toks_free(Tokens *tokens)
{
    free(tokens);
    free(tokens->toks);
}


void toks_print(Tokens *tokens)
{
    printf("Printing %i tokens:\n", tokens->tokno);
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens->tokno; i++) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", tokens->toks[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}


Tokens *tokenize(char *str, const char *delim)
{
    Tokens *tokens = toks_new();
    for (int n = 0; ; n++)
    {
        if (n != 0) str = NULL;
        char *token = strtok(str, delim);
        if (token == NULL)
        {
            tokens->tokno = n;
            break;
        } 
        tokens->toks[n] = token;
    }
    return tokens;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Tokens *program = NULL;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void read_assembly_program(const char *filepath)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filepath, "rt");

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long bytes = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    char buffer[bytes];
    fread(buffer, 1, bytes, file);

    // Without this I get an indecipherable line at the end... But why?
    buffer[bytes-1] = '\0';

    // What is printed is exactly what I expect, the whole content of the file
    printf("This is the file read:\n%s\n\n\n", buffer);

    program = tokenize(buffer, "\n");
    // This prints the tokens as expected
    toks_print(program);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    const char * file = "gpio_0.s";

    read_assembly_program(file);

    // But here the last two lines messed up!
    toks_print(program);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tokenize()` stores references to `buffer` into the data referred by `program`.

`buffer` is declared local to `read_assembly_program()` an so the memory isn't valid anymore after `read_assembly_program()` had been left.

To get around this pass down to `read_assembly_program()` a reference to the `buffer` or allocate `buffer` on the heap using `malloc()`.

---

**Update**

Two (not so nice) alternative solutions:

- Define the buffer globally.
- Declare the "local" buffer as `static`.

Comment: I think I understand what is going on...
But what if I don't want to allocate buffer on the heap or even carrying it around since once I'm outside read_assembly_program() I'm done with it and I no longer need it?

Comment: compiler complains that "Variable length array declaration can not have 'static' storage duration."
This is the thing, I want to get rid of buffer once I'm done with it, and be able to use my program variable to access the text from anywhere in my program.
Evidently I have to rethink the way tokenize() is implemented.